# how i can create 3d input / 3d output Convolution model with keras?

Tags: 3d, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

I have a bit question i couldnt solve.

I wanna implement CNN model with fully-connected MLP to my protein database which has 2589 proteins. Each protein has 1287 rows and 69 columns as input and and 1287 rows and 8 columns as output. Actually there was 1287x1 output, but i used one hot encoding for class labels to use crossentropy loss in my model.

Also i want

if we consider as image i have an 3d matrix ** X_train = (2589, 1287, 69) for input** and **y_train =(2589, 1287, 8) output**, i mean output is also matrix.

Below my codes of keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense((8), activation="softmax"))
```

But I encountered with Error about Dense layer :

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (2589, 1287, 8)
```

Ok, i understand that Dense should take positive integer unit (explanation in Keras docs. ). But how i can implement matrix output to my model ?

I tried that:

```
model.add(Dense((1287,8), activation="softmax"))
```

and something else but i couldnt find any solution.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Conv2D` layer requires an input shape of `(batch_size, height, width, channels)`. This means that each sample is a 3D array.

Your actual input is `(2589, 1287, 8)` meaning that each sample is of shape `(1289, 8)` - a 2D shape. Because of this, you should be using `Conv1D` instead of `Conv2D`.

Secondly you want an output of `(2589, 1287, 8)`. Since each sample is of a 2D shape, it makes no sense to `Flatten()` the input - `Flatten()` would reduce the shape of each sample to 1D, and you want each sample to be 2D.

Finally depending on the padding of your `Conv` layers,the shape may change based on the `kernel_size`. Since you want to preserve the middle dimension of `1287`, use `padding='same'` to keep the size the same.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Flatten, Dense
import numpy as np

X_train = np.random.rand(2589, 1287, 69)
y_train = np.random.rand(2589, 1287, 8)


model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(64, 
                 kernel_size=3, 
                 activation="relu", 
                 padding='same',
                 input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
model.add(Conv1D(32, 
                 kernel_size=3, 
                 activation="relu",
                 padding='same'))
model.add(Dense((8), activation="softmax"))

model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Im too greateful man, thanks very much. Its well explicative comment. i thought  2d mean like matrix (2dim). Thanks very much again.

Comment: Hi, if this answer solved your problem could you please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark on its side? Thanks.

Comment: can i ask a questiın too. What about Pooling layer ? When i use pooling layer, i get error about dimension size. I mean each input has (1287,69) and each class label (1287,8). But after the pooling layer, output shape will be reduced, how i can solve this problem ?

For example when i 2 convol layer and 2 pooling layer (with 2 size), i got this error : expected dense_2 to have shape (322, 8) but got array with shape (1287, 8)

Comment: Pooling layers will reduce the size of it's input. The error is caused when the pooling layer reduces the size but your y vector is still the original size. Use model.summary() to see the shapes at each layer on your model.