# How to have 3d output in keras with 3d input

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am trying to understand how the neural network architecture works.  Been reading some documents but get confuse about the input/output shape.

In my example I am trying to do the following.  Lets say I always have an input of (20, 15, 15).  Where there is a depth of 20 matrix with 15 rows x 15 cols per input.  Basically each input in a batch will be a 3d input.  I would like to have an output of depth 6 matrix with 15 rows x 15 cols each.  Which is also a 3d output.

[Somewhat similar question (3d input/3d output)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53601593/how-i-can-create-3d-input-3d-output-convolution-model-with-keras)

The question/answer in the link above makes sense for what he is looking for, but I couldnt seem to make it work for what I want.  Of course the neural network can be much deeper than below, but I am just trying to grasp the logic for now.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Conv1D, Conv2D, Conv3D
from keras.optimizers import Adam

class Model2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        self.model = Sequential()

        self.model.add(Conv2D(12, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(15, 15, 20)))
        self.model.add(Conv2D(10, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
        self.model.add(Dense((6), activation='softmax'))

        self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))

a = Model2()
a.model.summary()
```

output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 15, 12)        2172      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 15, 15, 10)        1090      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 15, 15, 6)         66        
=================================================================
Total params: 3,328
Trainable params: 3,328
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Which seems to make sense.  I am assuming with the output shapes its (batch size, x (cols), y (rows), z (depth)) for the 4 number respectively.  Which will then give me what I am looking for.

But from the question linked above, it confused me because of the order of the output shape.

From the link above, his solution for the conv1d was:

```
class Model1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.build_model()

    def build_model(self):
        self.model = Sequential()

        self.model.add(Conv1D(64, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(1287, 69)))
        self.model.add(Conv1D(32, kernel_size=3, activation='relu', padding='same'))
        self.model.add(Dense((8), activation='softmax'))

        self.model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))

a = Model1()
a.model.summary()
```

output:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_1 (Conv1D)            (None, 1287, 64)          13312     
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_2 (Conv1D)            (None, 1287, 32)          6176      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1287, 8)           264       
=================================================================
Total params: 19,752
Trainable params: 19,752
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Where in his example he has 1287 rows, 69 cols as input initially.  And his intended output is 1287 rows and 8 cols.

In short is the output shape for 4 numbers is (batch, x, y, z) then for 3 numbers its (batch, y, x)?  Assuming x is col, y is row, and z is depth.  Is that accurate? Seems confusing...

When I change my input_shape to (20,15,15) instead of (15,15,20) my output will be very different:

```
Model: "sequential_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 20, 15, 12)        1632      
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 20, 15, 10)        1090      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 20, 15, 6)         66        
=================================================================
Total params: 2,788
Trainable params: 2,788
Non-trainable params: 0
```

What is the order of input shape in terms of x, y, z.  Is it input_shape(x, y, z)? Or is it (z, y, x)  just like the order of a numpy array. And what is the order of the output shape when its 3 dimensions/4 dimensions. (Batch, z, y, x)?

Comment: Yup.  I mean 20 different matrix each 15x15.  I am assuming depth is same as z axis in three dimension

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the output shape of convolutional layer, the first dimension is batch and the last dimension is always depth. So, for 2D convolutions, the output shape will be (batch,y,x,z) and for 1D, (batch,x,z).

The output depth is always equal to the number of kernels of the layer.
For dense layer, the output also has the depth equal to the number of layer units.

Convolution kernel is "moving" across spatial dimensions (x,y) and result of different kernels is placed on different z-layers of the output.

In other words, if you have a convolutional layer `Conv2D(kernels,padding='same')` and you pass (batch,y,x,z) as input data to it, the output shape will be (batch,y,x,kernels).

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense.

Comment: Quick question.  For using numpy, isnt np.random.rand(1, 20, 15, 15) equals 1 batch, 20 depth, 15 rows, 15 cols? But of course this input wont work with the model since it will expect shape (15,15,20). If i change an input to train with np.random.rand(1, 15, 15, 20) the model will accept it, but if I print it out, this has a depth of 15, rows of  15 and cols of 20.

Comment: Yes, this is just the way how numpy prints arrays - it interprets last 2 dimensions as rows and cols. Keras/Tensorflow by default interpret last dimension as depth (or "channels" for image data). You can change it by setting 'data_format' parameter of conv layer. Read about it here: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional

Answer (score 2):

In your example, the contents of the last dimension are known as `channels` or `features` (it is possible to have features as the second dimension, but I'm not going there in this answer). That being said, irrespective of what type of CNN you use, one of the dimensions will always be `channels`. Another dimension will always be "batch size". The remaining space is left for other dimensions.

So, for a batch of 15x15 image with depth 20, we have

x = 15

y = 15

z = 20

And after the first layer, we have

x = 15 (since padding is "same". If it was "valid", the value would be 13)

y = 15 (similar to x)

z = 64 (The first parameter of the layer).

However, in case of 1D convolutions, the corresponding shape cannot be called (batch_size, y, x). A more accurate representation (going by the nomenclature in the answer) would be (batch_size, x, z) : The last dimension is specified by the programmer.

In `keras`, when using a dense layer for an input having more than 2 dimensions (i.e., (batch_size, features)), the last axis is the one that is modified by the layer. The shape of the remaining axes remain the same.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!